# Get count of records in file with a filter in file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting, cut

I have a file | delimited, File has 4 columns

```
123|456|789|234
456|456|789|2345
124|456|789|2345
125|456|789|2345
126|456|789|2345
128|451|782|2345
```

Output --> 6

How can find the count of distinct records in column1 where col2=456 and col3=789.

I know how to find the distinct of col1 for whole file, but how do we find after applying some filter on other column

Comment: Do you want output 5, the last line should be skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`'n `cut`'n `sort`'n `wc`'n a bunch of pipes:

```
$ grep ^[^\|]*\|456\|789\| file | cut -d \| -f 1-3 | sort -u | wc -l
5
```

Demonstrated:

```
$ grep ^[^\|]*\|456\|789\| file  # search for ^...|456|789|
123|456|789|234
456|456|789|2345
124|456|789|2345
125|456|789|2345
126|456|789|2345
```

and pipe it to

```
cut -d \| -f 1-3               # to lose the last field
123|456|789
456|456|789
124|456|789
125|456|789
126|456|789
```

and on to

```
sort -u                        # sort and get unique records
123|456|789
124|456|789
125|456|789
126|456|789
456|456|789
```

and finally

```
wc -l                          # count them
5
```

Super Mario's daily bread:

```
|
```

Comment: With the fixed columns you can do `grep "|456|789|" file | cut -d"|" -f1 | sort -u | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'|' '$2==456 && $3==789 && !a[$1,$2,$3]++{count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```

Comment: @Vijiy, sure creating an array with index of $1,$2 and $3 and !a[...]]++ means condition will be only TRUE when 1st occurence of these 3 items are coming in array, once condition true then variable count's value will be incremented by 1 and at the end in END section printing value of value of count.

Comment: @Vijiy, will add full explanation in few mins too in my post.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, I get the unique count from all lines. Indeed, I see no attempt at filtering by column.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you sir for letting know, I have edited it now.

Comment: The keys $2 and $3 are redundant, but if you remove them you get what I posted already.

Comment: @tripleee the keys are not redundant, they are needed (`$1`) might already exist in a case where the first two conditions do not satisfy and this might give you a miss. There is nothing that states that `cond2` should not be evaluated if `cond1` fails in an expression as `cond1 && cond2` (or is there?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Awk script.

```
awk -F '|' '$2=="456" && $3=="789" { if (!a[$1]++) count++ }
    END { print count }' file
```

Your sample data contains 5 distinct values in column 1 with these constraints.

If you want to pass in the values as parameters,

```
c2="456"
c3="789"
awk -F '|' -v col2="$c2" -v col3="$c3" '$2==col2 && $3==col3 {
        if (!a[$1]++) count++ }
    END { print count }' file
```

The array `a` collects the keys from column 1 which we have already seen. If the array doesn't contain the value of the first column already, we add 1 to `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
perl -lne ' /^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|/ and $2==456 and $3==789 and $kv{$1}++ ; END { print scalar keys %kv } '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat vijiy.txt
123|456|789|234
456|456|789|2345
124|456|789|2345
125|456|789|2345
126|456|789|2345
128|451|782|2345
$ perl -lne ' /^(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|/ and $2==456 and $3==789 and $kv{$1}++ ; END { print scalar keys %kv } ' vijiy.txt
5
$
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different logic than the previous awk solutions. But than also slightly:

```
awk -F '|' '($2!=246 || $3!=789){next}!a[$1]++{c++}END{print c}' file
```